# jQuery slide down to full height? How does jQuery know the element's full height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on some folding functions for a form similar to sublime text's code folding. I want to be able to animate between 20px and the full height of a div. I tried doing `el.animate({'height':'20px'});` and then `el.slideUp();`, but jQuery won't slide the element if the height is already set.

Is there a simple way to do this with jQuery, and how does jQuery know what to animate the height to when you do `.slideDown()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the full height of an element with **"display: block"**;

So in case you have a hidden element, you can set it's position to **absolute**, position it out of the screen and grab it's dimensions like this:

```
$('#el').css('position', 'absolute').css('left', '99999px').css('display', 'block');
var h = $('#el').height();
$('#el').css('position', 'relative').css('display', 'none');
```

As for your issue, check that you are sliding once the animation is done.
Use:

```
el.animate({'height':'20px'}, delay, function() { slide here })
```

Comment: Well if jQuery's solution is that hacky, I'll just grab the height and store it in the element's data before hiding it. I was planning on doing that, but I thought there might have been a better solution, but I suppose not.

Comment: In JS a lot of things that require DOM manipulation are a bit hacky.. :) Take it as a natural thing. I do not know jQuery's solution in this case - this is how I managed to do that